# How can handle 2 or more than 2 instances of CKEditor using port (like GoogleDocs)

Tags: php, ckeditor, google-docs

I have been asked by my one office fellow who is working on a project in which he have to make a document editor using CKEditor and if the same document is opened by another user then it should behave like Google Docs.

Like, changed characters by user A should be synced with user B's editor and vice versa.

By default, we can do that on blur User A's content will be shifted to User B's editor but in that case User B's changes will be lost.

Please advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My company has strived for a similar solution and to date has not found any solution with a php backend. Sockets would be an optimal way to achieve this but php support isn't quite where we want it. We looked at switching to NodeJs to utilize its socket support and developed a working prototype. The current agenda doesn't include implanting that full-scale yet but hopefully someday. For now we just display a message to the user that another user is editing a particular portion of the document (usually there are ~5-10 various pieces so it isn't such an issue) so it is like that content is locked for editing...

Comment: Yes you are right. that we can display a notification that other user is updating this content.

What if we just get startChangingPosition, updated characters from the editor of User A and then update User B's editor by that parameters ... Whats your suggestion that will it work ?

Comment: Hmm unfortunately I don't see anything in the [ckeditor docs](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR) about getting the position of the cursor. I found [a forum post about getting the position](http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor/Any-way-to-getset-cursorcaret-location) from last year that allows you to get the selected paragraph/word - I tried the following on the ckeditor demo page: 
    `var selection = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getSelection();     selection.selectElement(selection.getStartElement());`

Comment: @Aelliott1485OK I will forward to my office fellow maybe he can achieve his goal. Anyway, thanks for your time. I will update here If we get some success.